how create signedTransactionRaw without using module in swift
I try to create signedTransactionRaw for request to infura url to make some event in ethereum node but when i try to below to code i get error
func transaction() {
   var rawTransaction : CodableTransaction = .emptyTransaction            
   rawTransaction.from = senderAddress
   rawTransaction.to = senderAddress
   rawTransaction.nonce = BigUInt(0)
   rawTransaction.data = Data()
   rawTransaction.value = BigUInt(0.0001)
   rawTransaction.gasPrice = BigUInt(20000000000) // 20 Gwei
   rawTransaction.gasLimit = BigUInt(21000)

   try rawTransaction.sign(privateKey: privateKeyData)

   let rawTransactionHex = "0x" + rawTransaction.encode()!.toHexString()
   sendTransaction(infuraUrl: infuraURL, signedTransactionHex: rawTransactionHex )
}

func sendTransaction(infuraUrl: String, signedTransactionHex: String) {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction",
        "params": [signedTransactionHex],
        "id": 1
    ]
    
    AF.request(infuraUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Transaction sent successfully: \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error sending transaction: \(error)")
            }
        }
}


I get errors like these
Transaction sent successfully: {
    error =     {
        code = "-32000";
        message = "invalid sender";
    };
    id = 1;
    jsonrpc = "2.0";
}

Transaction sent successfully: {
    error =     {
        code = "-32602";
        message = "Invalid method parameters transaction type";
    };
    id = 1;
    jsonrpc = "2.0";
}

